# HTML & PHP arithmetic calculations based on input given

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get user input then make calculation based on the input.

Below is the main html. please help

```
<html>
    <body>
        Welcome there, <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>
        <br><br>
        ---- YOUR SELECTION -----
        <br><br>
    <?php
        $quantity = = echo $_POST["quantity"];
        var_dump($quantity);
        $bidprice = = echo $_POST["bidprice"];
        var_dump($bidprice);
        $total = = $quantity * $bidprice;
        var_dump($total);
    ?>
        Quantity selected: <?php echo $_POST["quantity"]; ?>
        <br>
        Bid price: <?php echo $_POST["bidprice"]; ?>
        <br> 
        Total: <?php echo $total; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is the form that replies based on input, but it can get the name but can't perform calculation. Why?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="welcome_get.php" method="post">
            What is your name?
            <input type="text" name="name">
            <br><br>
            Quantity:
            <input type="number" name="quantity">
            <br>
            Bid Price:
            <input type="number" name="bidprice">
            <br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please always add all question details to your question body via edit.  Copy-paste into the question box, highlight the codeblock, then press `Ctrl-K`.  Then delete your comments

Comment: You don't use `echo` to declare variable values and only one `=` is necessary to perform a value assignment.

Comment: Is my edit correct? `$quantity = = echo $_POST["quantity"];`, this is rather weird

Comment: @mickmackusa ok noted with thanks, am new to this

Comment: Here's a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16876209/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/35138101/2943403

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/a/9554010/2943403

Answer (score 0):

You have added `"= ="`  while assigning to variable like `$quantity = = $_POST["quantity"];` This will not allow in php & you don't need to add `"echo"` while assigning value to variable.

Following example will help you to learn PHP Sintax

```
<html>
        <body>
            Welcome there, <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>
            <br><br>
            ---- YOUR SELECTION -----
            <br><br>
        <?php
            $quantity = $_POST["quantity"];
           $bidprice = $_POST["bidprice"];
            $total = $quantity * $bidprice;
          ?>
            Quantity selected: <?php echo $_POST["quantity"]; ?>
            <br>
            Bid price: <?php echo $_POST["bidprice"]; ?>
            <br> 
            Total: <?php echo $total; ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Output:

```
Welcome there, Shivrudra Samshette 

---- YOUR SELECTION ----- 

Quantity selected: 2 
Bid price: 100 
Total: 200
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much, I'm a beginner thanks for helping out

Comment: @mickmackusa, i am new to stackoverflow. is it ok now?.

Comment: @JasonYeap if this code is working properly then Upvote for the same.